# PHP Mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

i'm new to mod_rewrite, and i'm trying to convert my web address from:

```
website.com/profile.php?user=andy
```

to the following:

```
website.com/user/andy
```

This is my following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

I researched extensively and this does seem to be the correct way to do it, but it doesn't redirect to where i want it to, it just redirects to this:

```
http://website.com/profile.php?user=andy
```

which means i must doing something wrong...

Can anyone help me out here? I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: Your code is correct. Did you give the link like <a href="http://website.com/user/andy">Test</a>. If so, then it will redirect to profile.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want

- `http://website.com/profile.php?user=andy` ->301-> `http://website.com/user/andy`
- `http://website.com/user/andy` means `http://website.com/profile.php?user=andy`

They are 2 different things, you'll need 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=([A-Za-z0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^profile.php /user/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^user/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ profile.php?a=b&user=$1 [L]
```

The first will 301 (moved permanently) redirect to the pretty url.
The second will allow your application to understand the pretty url.

Whenever you change the url scheme for a site you should take care of existing links. As such, that first rule is required/a good idea. You should not, however, need the first rule when using your own application. If your own application is generating links to profile.php?user=me - change your application code.

Comment: Hey AD7, thank you so much, i read over some more mod_rewrite, and your way does seem to be the RIGHT way. It is the 301 that physically redirects to a prettier url. I copied and pasted your code to the .htaccess, but it still doesn't direct to website.com/user/andy , rather, it goes to website.com/profile.php?user=andy . If i go to website.com/user/andy, it does work though. AHHH this is so confusing T.T

Comment: lol sorry im new. I noticed that you changed the code. Thanks so much for that. It finally redirects to website.com/user/andy but the page says "this page isn't redirecting properly, firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. I'm not sure what this means o.o

Comment: Chrome gives the error: Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Comment: I think for the second line, maybe the L should be taken out? cuz doesn't the L stop running the rules, such as that the third line won't be reached? But RewriteRule ^profile.php /user/%1? [R=301]
doesn't seem to work either :/

Comment: tip: use copy and paste. and try the php chat room for "interactive" help, not comments.

Comment: omg, i took your tip and copy and pasted it...and it worked? What I had before was the same thing as the copy and paste, and now it works o.O Does the spacing of the lines affect the outcome? Thank you so much dude, you were really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your URLs when outputting them in your HTML to be in the format you want (/user/andy).

mod_rewrite will rewrite /user/andy to main.php?... not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by *my result*?

mod_rewrite won't change existing links in your source code. Navigate to `website.com/user/andy` and you should see it work.

Comment: Hey alex! i meant result as in, when I log in, it will take me to that url and not the one i want (i re-edited, thanks for pointing that out). I tried your suggestion, and website.com/user/andy does seem to work if i go there, but it doesn't physically change on the url bar. How do i get it to physically change the words to website.com/user/andy and not website.com/profile.php?user=andy

Comment: Thank you so much for the help alexn and AD7